# Flex-box with grow height: different result between Chrome and Other browsers

Tags: css, flexbox

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="test">
        <div style="height: 10000px; background: white; margin: 60px;">
            This is inner div
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;   
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 60px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

#test {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

When the inner div's height is very large, for example 10000px, the expected result is #main's height keepping no change. Chrome presents the expected layout. But other browsers will increase the height of #test and #main:

[codepen demo here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WgrVNp)

Is there something wrong with my code?

(New to flexbox and world change a lot since 2002...)

Comment: Add `min-height: 0` to `#main`. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dqMyNj